# OutputStream translating bytes into characters with charset (opposite of OutputStreamWriter)

Tags: java, character-encoding

I need to manipulate content as it is being written to an OutputStream. Specifically, I need to replace CR or LF with CRLF to canonicalize text. This is easy for simple character sets where CR=13 and LF=10, but not so simple with multi-byte character sets. The **characters** should be replaced, not the **bytes**. It is non-trivial in general to do that in the output stream itself.

The built-in class OutputStreamWriter converts from characters to bytes for a configured encoding. I'm looking for a class that does the opposite, that is an OutputStream configured with a character set that buffers data as needed and translates the written bytes into characters with the character set (or throws on invalid byte sequences), making the characters available in some way, for example by forwarding the call to a Writer.

In other words I want to convert from bytes to characters on-the-fly as content is being written. I could write everything to a buffer and read it back with an InputStreamReader, but that is inefficient for very large payloads that won't fit in memory.

Is there a class like this somewhere (ideally open source, as I don't think it is built in)? If not, are there similar examples for efficient streaming conversion I could use as a starting point? The JDK classes I've seen are optimized for converting many bytes at a time, not for streaming use.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Writer`, maybe a `FilterWriter` that replace occurrences of `CR` or `LF` with characters `CR` and `LF`. You need to use an `InputStreamReader` for the conversion of bytes to characters. Conversion from bytes to characters generally doesn't make sense when *writing* (as the eventual target of a write is almost always a sink for bytes).

Comment: Sounds like you want ```FilterWriter```

Comment: Mark, I need to present an OutputStream to the calling code and I specifically wrote that I don't want to buffer the very large content to be able to read it with an InputStreamReader. I need to convert from bytes to characters on the fly (streaming).

Comment: g00se, a FilterWriter is a Writer, not an OutputStream. You call it with characters or strings. The calling code expects an OutputStream that accepts bytes. I need a class that converts from bytes to characters. Otherwise a filter is what I'm looking for, but it must be from OutputStream to Writer (or similar) - bytes to characters.

Comment: Why do you think you need to load fully into memory to be able to do that. In any case, I suggest you explain your problem in more detail, and why it is not possible for you to replace bytes 0x0A and 0x0D with two bytes 0x0D 0x0A on the fly.

Comment: ```FilterOutputStream``` also exists if that's more appropriate

Comment: I cannot replace 0x0A and 0x0D to 0x0D 0x0A as that won't work with UTF-16 (or by all means exotic EBCDIC encodings - I don't know the charset in advance). You have a point about not having to buffer everything, perhaps a PipedOutputStream would work. I would prefer something that is designed for streaming conversion, though. InputStreamReader is designed for bulk conversion (see comments in source code). EDIT: pipe streams virtually require multiple threads, which is not at all ideal.

Comment: FilterOutputStream reads bytes and writes bytes. The difficulty is to convert the incoming bytes to characters (before converting back to bytes and writing). I could use a FilterOutputStream, but I would need to do the character conversion which is the difficult part.

Comment: A solution could be using a `FilterOutputStream` that accepts the bytes, uses `CharsetDecoder` to convert to char and write to a `Writer`, but I'm just guessing without having explored if that works for this case (or if there are easier solutions).

Comment: Yes, that (OutputStream using CharsetDecoder) is about right. Ideally I would prefer an existing class along those lines that has been tested and performance tuned. If there is none I could implement it myself. I think I have read in a StackOverflow post that CharsetDecoder is inefficient when called byte-by-byte, though.

Comment: It will probably require piped streams (which I was about to recommend) though the basis should probably be still be ```FilterX``` . You can't realistically code for arbitrary encodings - that's really a GIGO problem

Comment: I can code for arbitrary encodings supported by the JDK: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html. That is a lot. It also varies with platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an implementation based on CharsetDecoder. Create a decoder and allocate a ByteBuffer and CharBuffer in the constructor:

```
decoder = charset.newDecoder();
byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
charBuf = CharBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
```

Then implement write:

```
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    if (!byteBuf.hasRemaining()) {
        decodeAndWriteByteBuffer(false);
    }
    byteBuf.put((byte) b);
}
```

And decodeAndWriteByteBuffer:

```
private void decodeAndWriteByteBuffer(boolean endOfInput) throws IOException {
    byteBuf.flip();
    CoderResult cr;
    do {
        cr = byteBuf.hasRemaining() || endOfInput
           ? decoder.decode(byteBuf, charBuf, endOfInput)
           : CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
        if (cr.isUnderflow()) {
            if (endOfInput) {
                do {
                    cr = decoder.flush(charBuf);
                    writeCharBuffer();
                } while (cr.isOverflow());

                if (cr.isError()) {
                    cr.throwException();
                }
            }
        } else if (cr.isOverflow()) {
            writeCharBuffer();
        } else {
            cr.throwException();
        }
    } while (cr.isOverflow());
    byteBuf.compact();
}
```

The remaining details are left as an exercise to the reader. It seems to work, though it is to early to say anything about performance.